# How to show different content to the users of my web app? MERN stack

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, mongoose

I'm trying to make a voting app in which every user can vote only once. To accomplish that I save the ip of the users that have already voted and compare them to the one of whoever is using the app. so if his ip match one that is already in the database he would get a screen saying he can't vote again.
The problem is that if one user voted every other user gets the screen saying they cant vote.

This is the backend code to get the user ip and all the ip in the db, and to post the ip if the vote:

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const ipify = require("ipify");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const internalIp = require("internal-ip");

const ipModel = require("../../models/Ip");

// @route   GET api/ip
// @desc    obtener todas las ip de la db
// @access  public
router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  ipModel
    .find()
    .then(ip => {
      res.status(200).json(ip);
    })
    .catch(err => res.status(404).json(err));
});

// @route   POST api/ip
// @desc    Guardar la ip en la db
// @access  public
router.post("/", (req, res) => {
  internalIp
    .v4()
    .then(miip => {
      ipModel
        .findOne({ ip: miip })
        .then(laip => {
          if (laip) {
            return res
              .status(400)
              .json({ ip: "Su voto se ha realizado exitosamente" });
          } else {
            const newIp = new ipModel({
              ip: miip
            });
            newIp.save().then(ip => res.json(newIp));
          }
        })
        .catch(err => res.status(404).json(err));
    })
    .catch(err => res.json(err));
});

// @route   GET api/ip/miip
// @desc    Guardar la ip en la db
// @access  public
router.get("/miip", (req, res) => {
  internalIp
    .v4()
    .then(miip => {
      res.status(200).json(miip);
    })
    .catch(err => res.json(err));
});

module.exports = router;
```

This is the code for the component that manages the votes logic in the frontend:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { Container, ListGroup, ListGroupItem, Button } from "reactstrap";
import { CSSTransition, TransitionGroup } from "react-transition-group";
import axios from "axios";

class Votos extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      carrozas: [],
      ipRegistradas: [],
      miIp: null,
      goToVotos: true
    };
    this.votar = this.votar.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("/api/ip")
      .then(ips => {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
          ipRegistradas: [...prevState.ipRegistradas, ...ips.data]
        }));
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));

    axios
      .get("/api/carrozas")
      .then(carrozasdb => {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
          carrozas: [...prevState.carrozas, ...carrozasdb.data]
        }));
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));

    axios
      .get("/api/ip/miip")
      .then(miip => {
        this.setState({
          miIp: miip.data
        });
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }

  shouldRedirect() {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.state.ipRegistradas.length; i++) {
      if (this.state.ipRegistradas[i].ip === this.state.miIp) {
        this.setState({
          goToVotos: false
        });
      }
    }
  }

  votar(nom) {
    axios.post("/api/votos", { nombre: nom });
    axios.post("/api/ip");
  }

  render() {
    const { carrozas } = this.state;
    this.shouldRedirect();

    if (this.state.goToVotos === true) {
      return (
        <Container>
          <h3
            style={{
              display: "flex",
              justifyContent: "center",
              alignItems: "center"
            }}
          >
            Votá la mejor carroza...
          </h3>
          <ListGroup>
            <TransitionGroup className="carrozas">
              {carrozas.map(({ _id, nombre, curso }) => (
                <CSSTransition key={_id} timeout={500} classNames="fade">
                  <ListGroupItem
                    style={{
                      display: "flex",
                      justifyContent: "spaceAround"
                    }}
                  >
                    <Button
                      className="votar-btn"
                      color="primary"
                      size="sm"
                      onClick={() => {
                        this.votar(nombre);
                        this.props.history.push("/votoexitoso");
                      }}
                    >
                      Votar
                    </Button>
                    "{nombre}"
                    <p
                      style={{
                        marginLeft: "5rem"
                      }}
                    >
                      {curso}
                    </p>
                  </ListGroupItem>
                </CSSTransition>
              ))}
            </TransitionGroup>
          </ListGroup>
        </Container>
      );
    } else {
      return <Redirect to="votoexitoso" />;
    }
  }
}

export default Votos;
```

Answer (score 0):

`internal-ip` gives you your **server** IP address. To get the client IP address you can use `request.connection.remoteAddress` or `request.headers['x-forwarded-for']` if the server is behind a proxy.

```js
router.post("/", (req, res) => {
    const ip = req.connection.remoteAddress;
    ...
```

Comment: and how would using the client IP address instead of the server IP address solve the problem?

Comment: AFAIK when a user votes, you're storing his IP address in the database and allowing to vote only if his IP address is not found in the database(Is that right?). If you use your server IP address, you're actually comparing your server address with previously stored server address and because of that everyone gets 'can't vote' message.

Comment: I've tried your solution and it worked. Thank you. But I have another problem now. Every time I vote using the app in a phone, a different IP address is save in the database for the same device, so its always allow to vote

Comment: Generally, the IP addresses are not a reliable method for identifying users identity, they are dynamic and can change over time. If you need to be 100 percent sure that this user has not previously voted, consider using another method such as registration.

Comment: The thing is I dont want users to loose time registrating. Maybe if I use cookies instead of the IP address or a registration method?

Comment: Actually, cookies are better idea than using IP addresses but they are not secure. A normal user without any knowledge about software development can go and clear the browser cookies and repeat the voting process. Bots, on the other hand, can do this without human intervention.